# App crashing after selecting photo from gallery

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I created an image processing app which shows percentage of similarity between images using openCV. However, whenever I select an image the application process crashes.

Here is the logcat:

```
E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: softwareengineering.pwc.leafidentifierv2, PID: 1036
              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 52985868 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 15MB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:701)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:508)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:541)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:512)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:572)
                  at softwareengineering.pwc.leafidentifierv2.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:161)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4280)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4327)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1624)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

and here is the line in mainactivity 161

```
toMatch[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cleaf5);
```

Comment: How big is the photo in terms of height and width?

Comment: The meassage isn't clear *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 52985868 byte* ? The Picture has 52 MB and does not fit in your memory

Comment: Even though it doesn't seem like it matches any reason to close (Other than typographical since the OP didn't read or understand the log), I'd vote to close this. You don't have enough memory; it clearly says this (I dont mean to be mean, but, it says it right there). If the question is why can't you allocate that much, since it's not a lot of RAM, then please reword it. Though, it's also clearly telling you that you only have 4MB + 15MB to work with, btw, so idk if it really helps the triviality of this problem.

Comment: If you believe you should have more than 19MB available for your App, please give all of the reasons why ("RAM available on phone is 1GB", etc).

Answer (score 1):

Your file is too big.
Add try-catch block and try to load smaller images with options.inSampleSize (try different values for options.inSampleSize)

Example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;

try{
bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cleaf5, options);
}catch(OutOfMemoryError e)    
   try{
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inSampleSize = 8;
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cleaf5, options);
   }catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {}
}

if(bitmap != null){
//do smth
}
```