# android cropped image expanding into its original crop

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, crop

I would like to show a cropped image in android that expands every second for 30 seconds, into its original crop. If this doesn't make any sense, please let me know and I will try to explain.

And is it possible to load an image from a URL? If so, how?

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 4:**

[image]

**Image 5:**

[image]

Comment: Provide us some pieces of code and some explanation. Is it an ImageView !? how does it occur?

Comment: I don't have a code yet. I was thinking of an image view that showed a cropped image, and over 30 seconds the image expands back to its original scale, for example like an animation. I hope this answers your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with SurfaceView.

Just draw particular part of bitmap on the canvas and expand it each iteration in while loop in your draw thread.

If I understand you right, this code will do the job:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ExpandView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private DrawThread drawThread;

    public ExpandView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_ID);

        drawThread = new DrawThread(holder, bitmap);
        drawThread.setRunning(true);
        drawThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        boolean retry = true;

        drawThread.setRunning(false);

        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    private class DrawThread extends Thread {
        private static final int FRAME_RATE = 30;
        private static final float ANIMATION_SPEED_MILLIS = 10_000;

        private Bitmap newBitmap;
        private int canvasWidth;
        private int canvasHeight;
        private int bitmapWidth;
        private int bitmapHeight;

        private boolean isRunning;
        private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private long startTime;
        private long lastDrawTime;
        private Paint paint;

        //crop rate should be >=0 and <= 1
        private float startCropRate = 0.2f;
        private float targetCropRate = 1;
        private float currentCropRate;

        private boolean expand;

       private int verticalOffset;
       private int horizontalOffset;
       private int newWidth;
       private int newHeight;
       private int newX;
       private int newY;

        public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

            canvasWidth = surfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame().width();
            canvasHeight = surfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame().height();

            this.bitmap = resizeBitmap(bitmap, canvasHeight, canvasWidth);

            bitmapWidth =  this.bitmap.getWidth();
            bitmapHeight =  this.bitmap.getHeight();

            paint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            expand = startCropRate > targetCropRate;
        }

        private Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bm, int canvasHeight, int canvasWidth) {
            int width = bm.getWidth();
            int height = bm.getHeight();

            float scale = Math.min(canvasWidth/(float)width, canvasHeight/(float)height);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    bm, 0, 0,width,height, matrix, false);
            bm.recycle();

            return resizedBitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Canvas canvas;
            long currentTime;
            long animationTime;
            float newScale;

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (isRunning) {

                if (currentCropRate == targetCropRate) {
                    isRunning = false;
                    return;
                }

                currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (currentTime - lastDrawTime < 1000 / FRAME_RATE) {
                    continue;
                }

                animationTime = currentTime - startTime;


                newScale = startCropRate + (targetCropRate - startCropRate) * (animationTime / ANIMATION_SPEED_MILLIS);

                currentCropRate = expand ? Math.max(targetCropRate, newScale) : Math.min(newScale, targetCropRate);

                lastDrawTime = currentTime;

                canvas = null;

                try {

                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

                        drawImage(canvas);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void drawImage(Canvas canvas) {

            newWidth = (int) (bitmapWidth * currentCropRate);
            newHeight = (int) (bitmapHeight * currentCropRate);

            newX = (bitmapWidth - newWidth) / 2;
            newY = (bitmapHeight - newHeight) / 2;

            newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, newX, newY,newWidth,newHeight);

            verticalOffset = (canvasHeight - newBitmap.getHeight()) / 2;
            horizontalOffset =  (canvasWidth - newBitmap.getWidth()) / 2;

            canvas.drawBitmap(newBitmap, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, paint);
        }


        private void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.isRunning = running;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to create method to pass image resource id or bitmap to this view, because this example works with hardcoded value.
And you can add different methods to restart animation, play animation on demand and different custom behaviours.

Also look at my answer about how to prevent OutOfMemoryError when decoding image resource here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52428066/10382361

There was example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;

try{
bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cleaf5, options);
}catch(OutOfMemoryError e)    
   try{
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inSampleSize = 8;
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cleaf5, options);
   }catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {}
}

if(bitmap != null){
//do smth
}
```

Comment: an example would be nice

Comment: Ok, I'll make it for you, just wait I need to finish some work.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how do I direct this code to a specific image view? So you can see the progress live.

Comment: This code is a ready-to-use View. Just create ExpandView.class in your project and copy this code there. Then add this view to your layout.xml. 
Replace `R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_ID` with some image resource from your res/drawable folder  (in the line 
 `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_ID);`)

And check how it works.

Comment: This results with an Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.(app_name).(app_name)/com.(app_name).(app_name).ExpandView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.(app_name).(app_name).ExpandView> has no zero argument constructor

Comment: the image is added to the question(image 4)

Comment: Oh. Seems like you are vey new with android development.
ExpandView  cant be Context. 
Put it inside like a simple view.
`<ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<(YOUR_PATH_TO_VIEW).ExpandView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
</ConstraintLayout>`

Comment: <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.(app_name).(app_name).ExpandView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Did you remove it from context?

Comment: I removed the context line

Comment: the image is added to the question(image 5)

Comment: You added image of your layout. I need your Activity class file

Comment: that code is identical to your, except the image resource id

Comment: I didn't post any Activity code, so it can't be identical to my. 
You should have at least one Activity class in your project to have something on the screen.
If you create new project with activity in Android studio it will have "MainActivity" name by default.
So I need code of your Activity class.

Comment: Now i understand.

Comment: Now I understand. I need to go, but I'll be back in an hour or so

Comment: Ok.
You have `setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_ID)` function call in your Activity's `onCreate` function, so put your layout (from image 5) as argument of that function and you will see how it works.
You will have something like 

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}`

Comment: is it possible to load an image from a URL? If so, how?

Comment: this current example is not for loading your image from URL. But you can change it and it will. 
Now it takes image from the resources folder.
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_ID);`

Comment: i tried using this code: Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

Comment: First of all, you can't connect to the internet on main thread. 
Use AsyncTask, for example, to load image.
When picture is loaded start your drawing thread.

And add 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ` to your AndroidManifest.xml file